# Return a SUBSTRING with a known Prefix and Suffix Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a table that has a Prefix of variable length that always ends with `.` and a suffix of variable length that always begins with `-`.  The `-` can also be found in the string of text that I am looking for, so using REVERSE() is likely the best way to identify the suffix `-`.

ex: `Prefix1.ABC-123-Suffix1`

I'd like the SUBSTRING() result to look like: `ABC-123`

I was able to create both a `SUBSTRING()` to remove the Prefix and a `SUBSTRING()` to remove the suffix, but I'm having a hard time applying both.  The returned text can be variable length.

I'm trying to avoid declaring a variable, but am open to it.  I'd prefer to only use SUBSTRING(), REVERSE(), and CHARINDEX() if possible.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT [Col1]
       ,SUBSTRING((Col1),CHARINDEX('.', (Col1)) + 1, 999) AS [StrippedPrefix]
       ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Col1),CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Col1)) + 1, 999)) AS [StrippedSuffix]

--new SUBSTRING() with both Prefix and Suffix stripped

FROM [Table1]
```

Comment: what variation of SQL is this?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Col1 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Prefix1.ABC-123-Suffix1')

Select *
      ,String=Substring(Col1,charindex('.',Col1)+1,len(Col1)-charindex('.',Col1)-charindex('-',reverse(Col1)))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Col1                       String
Prefix1.ABC-123-Suffix1    ABC-123
```

As per M Ali's suggestion (Even better)

```
Select *
      ,String=PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col1 , '-', '.') , 3) + '-' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col1 , '-', '.') , 2) 
 From  @YourTable
```

Comment: @DataMan31 Happy to help

Comment: Another way could be `PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col1 , '-', '.') , 3) + '-' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col1 , '-', '.') , 2) from @YourTable` :)

Comment: @M.Ali Even better!  Ashamed I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Here the varaiable is only used as demo - should work with your table as well:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(100) = 'Prefix1.ABC-123-Suffix1'

SELECT @s,
       SUBSTRING(@s, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @s)-1) StrippedPrefix,
       SUBSTRING(@s, LEN(@s)-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@s))+2, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@s))) StrippedSuffix,
       SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('.', @s)+1, LEN(@s)-CHARINDEX('.', @s)-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@s))) NewString
```

Comment: Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
'NVARCHAR' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

Comment: The thing that is confusing me here is, @s variable.  Where do I define the column? the Column is never defined in the above query in the select statement.

Comment: Instead @s, use your column which contains the string

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)= 'Prefix1.ABC-123-Suffix'

SELECT Reverse(Stuff(intr_str, 1, Charindex('-', intr_str), ''))
FROM   (SELECT Reverse(Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex('.', @str), '')) AS intr_str) a
```

**Result :** `ABC-123`

Comment: I received the same result